# CSS3 nth-child tiles background color alternate based on number of columns

Tags: css, css-selectors

Starting with the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/j5acY/

I have two ul elements. Both have li floating left. The CSS creates a tiled structure. I am alternating the background color of my li elements using nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd). Well, this works fine for the first UL which has 5 li elements in a row. For the second however, there are only 4 li elements in a row. As such even and odd set the background color correctly, but it does not look alternate. How do I make the second UL's li alternate such that the first element in each row is of alternate colors?

Hope I am making sense!

```
ul li:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #6a8bab;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: rgb(106, 170, 126);
}
```

http://www.clipular.com/c?5949919=sZxixdiI2WDpJIW27yoP4qoTreQ&f=.png

Comment: See logically it is showing the alternate color but in this view these are appearing as not alternate. you can check the color of 5th box in first ul and the 5th box of second ul both are having same color. Since the first ul is having odd numbers in one row so the alternate color is appearing below it.

Comment: I know that. I was trying to see how you could use nth-child(2n+1) like formula to select these! Or if there is another way of doing this. Has to be CSS, no javascript.

Comment: I don't know that there's any way to do this without involving some sort of mechanism that can provide advanced logic. CSS has no means by which you can ascertain if an element is going to reflow to the next line. Even using media queries would not fix this, as the li elements are always going to follow that set pattern, and you have no means of determining where your next row will begin from pure CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done, but it depends on the number of rows. If you only have two rows, the following will work:

```
ul.four li {
    background-color: silver;
}


ul.four li:nth-child(5n+1), ul.four li:nth-child(5n+3)   {
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5acY/1/

This repeats every 5th element, starting with the 1st, and again starting with the 3rd. It basically is a diagonal from top left to bottom right. It breaks if you add a 3rd row as the bottom left will not be black, so you'd need to manually select that, for example using `ul.four li:nth-child(9)`

http://jsfiddle.net/j5acY/2/

Of course if you add another row it will break again. Even if you used `ul.four li:nth-child(5n+9)`in the last example, we’ve hit the limit where the selector `ul.four li:nth-child(5n+3)` has started matching incorrectly and thus incorrectly matches the 13th element. You could then manually set it back to silver using `ul.four li:nth-child(13)`:

http://jsfiddle.net/j5acY/3/

This of course has to come after the previous rules setting the squares to black. As you can see, you will have to keep updating it if you add rows.

Another approach is infinitely scalable, but requires more work up front, and doesn't scale if more columns are added. With this approach you repeat every 8th element, starting with the first, then the third, sixth, and finally eighth:

```
ul.four li:nth-child(8n+1), ul.four li:nth-child(8n+3),
ul.four li:nth-child(8n+6), ul.four li:nth-child(8n+8){
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5acY/4/

As you can see, it doesn't matter how many rows you have. It will instantly break if you add more columns however. If you use 6 columns, you'll need to recalculate to repeat every 12th element and add more to handle the extra columns.

Comment: This is perfect. Especially the scalable one. Since this is for my responsive CSS, I have control over the break points. So, I can add the css for the specific media queries. Superb. Learnt something new! Thank you.